# getting strange coordinate values from vector<Point2f> in opencv

Tags: opencv

I have extracted 100 features points of an image using `vector<Point2f>connersFrame1` but i am getting segmentation fault while trying to access the pixel value of that image (480 * 640).

Then i tried to see the coordinate value using

```
cout<<"\n cornersFrame1[82]:  ("<<cornersFrame1[82].y<<" , "<<cornersFrame1[82].x<<")\n \n";
```

and i got the following output:

**cornersFrame1[83]:  (-1.68725   ,     317.552)**

How can i get the coordinate values in float form??

By the way, i am trying the following code to access the pixel values:

```
for(int i=0; i<cornersFrame1.size(); i++)
    {
        float value = calculatedU.at<float>(cornersFrame1[i]);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not be surprised of getting float values in general from feature detectors. Bear in mind, the detectors might be sophisticated tools that go deeply in the image knowledge (yep, literally - e.g. BRISK which use pattern idea which are scaled to find keypoints). In that case, you can just round the returned floated point to get ints.

But it is strange opencv can return negative point coordinates values. I think it is not proper opencv behavior. However, this small value (-1.68) is still acceptable because it usually detectors have some radius (or patch) on which they operate. But still opencv should have checked boundaries and it seems it does not.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that i am getting segmentation fault when i am trying to access the pixel values at the calculate feature points.

Comment: So do the bound checking by yourself. Do not allow to pass to Mat::at points that have negative coordinates or greater then image size by rounding them respectively to 0 and in your case 640 or 480. Which feature detector are you using?

Comment: i am using     goodFeaturesToTrack( frame1, cornersFrame1, maxCorners, qualityLevel, minDistance, Mat(), blockSize, useHarrisDetector, k );

Comment: Actually the problem is coming because of the negative values....i put a "if condition" and the problem got solved....but how is it possible that i am getting negative coordinate values for the detected features.